# Trigonometric identity inside an integral

Tags: integration

Hello I have one question, suppose I have this function
$$\frac{3\sin x\sin x/3}{x^2}$$
If I integrate this from zero to infinity the result is $\pi/2$.

Now $\frac{3\sin x\sin x/3}{x^2}$ is the same as
$$\frac3{2x^2}(\cos2x/3-\cos4x/3)$$
But if I try to integrate this latter expression with the same boundaries (Sum of two integrals, one for each cosine) this integral doesn't converge. Why? Are they not the same function?

Comment: _"this integral don't converge"_ [How so](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+(3+(cos((2+x)%2F3)+-+cos((4+x)%2F3)))%2F(2+x%5E2)+from+0+to+inf)?

Comment: The integral does converge, you just can't calculate is as the difference of the integrals of $$\frac3{2x^2}\cos2x/3$$ and $$\frac3{2x^2}\cos4x/3.$$

Comment: Thanks, Proferror Vector,  then I understand that when the cosine or sine function are involved in an integral, one can not apply the rule of separating the sums in different integrals, ok

Comment: @StackTD. Thanks, I tried it but separating it in two integrals, it was obviously wrong

Comment: It's not "when the cosine or sine function is involved." It's when the summands are not integrable. If $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\int_0^{\infty} g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ are finite, then $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)+g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ will be equal to the sum of the separate integrals.

Comment: @MichaelLee OK, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just an example not involving any trigonometric functions: $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent.
$1$ can be written as $(n+1)-n$ and both $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n+1}{n^2}$ and $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n}{n^2}$ are divergent, so
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(n+1)-n}{n^2}\color{red}{\neq}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n+1}{n^2}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n}{n^2}. $$